# Radio Buttons in breezypythongui library

Tags: python, radio-button, breezy

So I have a radio button group that I made using the breezypythongui library and I was curious if anyone could help me use it to execute a function.

```
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame

class Taxation(EasyFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        EasyFrame.__init__(self, title="Simple Tax Calculator")

        ##Input Income Field
        self.addLabel(text="Gross Income", row=0, column=0)
        self.grossIncome = self.addIntegerField(value=0, row=0, column=1, width=10)

        ##Deductions
        self.addLabel(text="Total Deductions", row=1, column=0)
        self.deductions = self.addIntegerField(value=0, row=1, column=1, width=10)

        ##Adjust Income
        self.addButton(text="Adjusted Income", row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, command=self.adjIncome)
        self.addLabel(text="Adjusted Gross Income", row=3, column=0)
        self.adjIncome = self.addFloatField(value=0.00, row=3, column=1, width=8, precision=2, state="readonly")


        ##Filing Status
        self.addLabel(text="Filing Status", row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")
        self.status = self.addRadiobuttonGroup(row=5, column=0, rowspan=4, columnspan=2)
        defaultRB = self.status.addRadiobutton(text="Single", value=1)
        self.status.setSelectedButton(defaultRB)
        self.status.addRadiobutton(text="Head of Household", value=2)
        self.status.addRadiobutton(text="Married Filing Jointly", value=3)
        self.status.addRadiobutton(text="Married Filing Separately", value=4)

        ##Output Button
        self.addButton(text="Taxes Owed", row=9, column=0, columnspan=2, command=self.statusSelection)

        ##Output
        self.addLabel(text="Total", row=10, column=0)
        self.outputField = self.addFloatField(value=0.00, row=10, column=1, width=8, precision=2, state="readonly")

    ##Income Adjustment Method
    def adjIncome(self):
        gross = self.grossIncome.getNumber()
        deductions = self.deductions.getNumber()
        adjIncome = gross - deductions
        self.adjIncome.setNumber(adjIncome)

    ##Event Method Handling
    def statusSelection(self):
        if value in self.status.getSelectedButton() == 1:
            self.single(self.adjIncome)


def main():
    Taxation().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The part I left out was 4 def's which are nothing more than if, elif, else statements about the income and they return a value.  I didn't include them because it is the entire federal tax bracket and this code is long enough as it is.

The problem I am having is that I can not get the "value" in the #Filing Status section to execute the corresponding function.